# TYPO3 | Wrap only if not equal to value

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Am using the following TS to customize my title tag to append the website name to the page title.

(Page title - Site Name).

```
config.noPageTitle = 2
page.headerData.5 = TEXT
page.headerData.5.field = subtitle // title
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>| - Site Name</title>
```

My issue is that I do not want it to appear on the Homepage since the page title there is the same as my site name. (So it says Site Name - Site Name).

My homepage is the tree root, and all other pages are under it.
I want to omit this condition only for Home page.

I am looking for such a condition,

```
WRAP ONLY IF NOT EQUALS 'Site Name'
```

How can I achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer from the Typo3 Mailing list.
Awesome support there.

In case anyone needs it, here it is.

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 10]
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>|</title>
[else]
page.headerData.5.wrap = <title>| - Site Name</title>
[end]
```

Now just change 10 to your homepage ID